# pyCharm Django error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using PyCharm. And in models.py I have such model:

```
class TaricCode(models.Model):
    code  = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Code")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, verbose_name="Description")
```

But in views.py when I write:

```
tc = TaricCode.objects.all()
```

`objects` is underlined as error "unresolved attribute reference" and code complete doesn't work for it. And when I run application it works.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have line

```
from django.db import models
```

And that Django package is actually in your Python path as set in PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I set path to my virtualenv interpreter only in "Run/Debug Configuration" and also I should install similar setting in "Settings" -> "Python Interpreter". Thanks. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: I'm importing my_models and my_models imports django.db.models. Why does PyCharm not know how to deal with that?
I don't like to add an 'unnecessary' line of code just for an editor.